# Compare SQL rows in same table and print out when there are differences

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
userid | name |      email       |  address 
-------+------+------------------+-----------
1      | joe  |  joe@gmail.com   |  123 Road 
1      | joe  |  joe@gmail.com   |  null
1      | joe  |     null         |  null
```

I want to return a row for each time the user has been changed and which row was changed. So

```
Userid  |   change   
--------+-----------
  1     |   added address
  1     |   added email
```

If two things were changed at once, I want the 'Change' column to include both.

Currently I am doing something like this

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN table1.email <> table2.email THEN 'Email Change'
        WHEN table1.email IS NULL AND table2.email IS NOT NULL THEN 'Email addition' 
END email,
CASE WHEN table1.address <> table2.address THEN 'Address Change'
        WHEN table1.address IS NULL AND table2.address IS NOT NULL THEN 'Address addition' 
END address
FROM usertable table1 JOIN usertable table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
```

And comparing each column. Then I will concatenate email and address in another select for display.

Was wondering if there is anything more efficient since I will be comparing a good amount of columns. Could LAG be applied here?

I cannot use SP or any type of loop due to restrictions of system. using oracle. Any ideas here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your tag says sql server.  your post says "using oracle"

Comment: if you are using oracle why you tag SQL-SERVER? please tag correctly

Comment: SQL-SERVER tag was suggested - accidentally hit it while trying to tag just SQL - sorry about that.

Comment: is there any column that specifies the ordering of these rows? and are these the only columns to be compared?

Comment: @vkp this is a small example of a larger picture. There are time stamps and should be ordered, but changes can happen in any order. I added some code in my question.

Comment: For a more "normalized" setup, each user would only have one entry in this table, and you might have a history table that you can log all changes and time of change to, so if any conflicts occur in your user table you can go back to the history table and find out what the data was like at a certain point in time.

Comment: You do need a timestamp to show things in some order; otherwise when you compare one row, which other row are you comparing it to? (And please don't say "the row before it in the table"; rows in a table are like ping-pong ball in a basket, they only **seem** ordered when you display them but you shouldn't think of them that way.)

Comment: @Edward this is actually how the db is set up - the table I am going through is the history table - I am going through and seeing what was changed.

Comment: @mathguy the timestamps can be used to order the data - and then we would want to look at the previous row (ordered by timestamp so it will always be the same). I'm not sure of the syntax to look at the previous row.

Comment: The I would suggest a query "Windowed" (in SQL-server: `RowNumber() over (partition by UserId order by UserId, timestamp)` ) so that you can the figure out which was changed from the last.

Comment: `lag()` (NOT `row_number()`) is indeed the right idea, and the syntax is `lag(address) over (partition by userid order by t_stamp)`. With that said: it would be better to have an output with several columns: `name_change, address_change, email_change` with values `null, added, deleted, updated`. Would that work for you? Also: what version of Oracle? In Oracle 12.1 and above, `match_recognize` may help.

Comment: @Edward: Why ask?  Google "Oracle lag"!

Comment: @mathguy - my version of oracle does support Lag - I have to return to one column with anything that was changed at one time (row of the history table) - However, I will be using this whole query as a subquery and returning separate values then concatenating so I don't have a huge case statement, rather many smaller ones - I have the idea now thanks to everyone's help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do this. (The OP has his answer already, but perhaps this will help future readers.) It seems a lot better to have the information in separate columns for each attribute - then they can be concatenated if really needed for reporting purposes. The format I show before is more flexible - it allows to see how many name changes a user had, vs. how many email changes.

```
with
     base_table ( userid, eff_dt, name, email, address ) as (
       select 1, date '2015-10-22', 'joe', 'joe@gmail.com', '123 Road' from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-03-20', 'joe', 'joe@gmail.com', null       from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-09-01', 'joe', null           , null       from dual
     )
select userid, eff_dt, name, email, address,
       case when lag(name) over (partition by userid order by eff_dt) is null
                 and name is not null then 'added'
            when lag(name) over (partition by userid order by eff_dt) is not null
                 and name is null     then 'deleted'
            when lag(name) over (partition by userid order by eff_dt) != name
                                      then 'updated'              end as name_changes,
       case when lag(email) over (partition by userid order by eff_dt) is null
                 and email is not null then 'added'
            when lag(email) over (partition by userid order by eff_dt) is not null
                 and email is null     then 'deleted'
            when lag(email) over (partition by userid order by eff_dt) != email
                                       then 'updated'             end as email_changes,
       case when lag(address) over (partition by userid order by eff_dt) is null
                 and address is not null then 'added'
            when lag(address) over (partition by userid order by eff_dt) is not null
                 and address is null     then 'deleted'
            when lag(address) over (partition by userid order by eff_dt) != address
                                         then 'update             end as address_changes
from   base_table
;
```

**Output**:

```
USERID EFF_DT     NAME EMAIL         ADDRESS  NAME_CHANGES EMAIL_CHANGES ADDRESS_CHANGES
------ ---------- ---- ------------- -------- ------------ ------------- ---------------
     1 2015-10-22 joe  joe@gmail.com 123 Road added        added         added
     1 2016-03-20 joe  joe@gmail.com                                     deleted
     1 2016-09-01 joe                                      deleted

 3 rows selected.
```

Comment: thanks for this answer- this is actually what I am doing as well. Will def help future readers. Thanks for all your input above.